# Evaluating a string of operations but code does not work

Tags: haskell

I need to write a code that evaluates a string of operations and outputs the resulting integer of that string. I wrote something but it's not working and would like some help. I need to use fold since it is easier but I'm sure what's wrong. This is on Haskell and using Emacs.

```
evalExpr :: String -> Int
evalExpr xs = foldl 0 xs where
  f v x | x == "+" = (+) v
        | x == "-" = (-) v
        | x == " " = 0
        | otherwise = read v :: Int
```

For example:

evalExpr "2+4+5-8"

the output should be: 3

evalExpr ""

the output should be: 0

This is because it should read the string left to right.

Comment: Where is your `f` in your `evalExpr`? And `f` is not type-checked. Notice the type signature of `foldl`: `(b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. Maybe you should use the [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) package to solve your problem.

Comment: @Z-Y.L what do you mean by f not type-checked?

Comment: `f` should always return the result of the same type and align with the type signature of `foldl`. In your case, `f`'s type signature should be `Int -> Char -> Int`, but yours is not.

Comment: @Z-Y.L any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: I suggest you first write it using recursion. Using a fold here would be harder, since you need to process more than one character at a time. E.g. when you need to read `"+3..."` you need to read both `+` and `3` to decide to increment the accumulator by 3. Reading only the `+` is not enough. Also, it's not clear if you need to handle numbers larger than 9 e.g. `23+543-765`: in such case, you need a smarter recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as @5ndG suggested. However, to evaluate a string of operations, using `parsec` is a better way. Here is an example for your case:

```
module EvalExpr where

-- You need parsec to do parsing work, and the following are just example 
-- modes for your simple case.
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String

-- A data structure for your simple arithmetic expresssion
data Expr = Lit Int
          | Plus Expr Expr
          | Minus Expr Expr
          deriving Show

-- Evaluate an Expr to an integer number
eval :: Expr -> Int
eval (Lit n) = n
eval (Plus e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
eval (Minus e1 e2) = eval e1 - eval e2

-- The following do the parsing work
-- Parser for an integer number
int :: Parser Expr
int = Lit . read <$> (many1 digit <* spaces)      -- A number may be followed by spaces

-- Parser for operators "Plus" and "Minus"
plus, minus :: Parser (Expr -> Expr -> Expr)
plus = Plus <$ char '+' <* spaces
minus = Minus <$ char '-' <* spaces

-- Parser for Expr
expr :: Parser Expr
expr = chainl int (plus <|> minus) (Lit 0)

-- Evalute string to an integer
evalExpr :: String -> Int
evalExpr s = case parse expr "" s of
               Left err -> error $ show err
               Right e  -> eval e
```

The above is just an simple example of using `parsec`. If your actual case is more complex, you'll need more work to do. So learning to use `parsec` is necessary. The [intro_to_parsing](https://github.com/JakeWheat/intro_to_parsing) is a good start. Also in the [package description](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) are there some learning resources.

By the way, `Text.Parsec.Expr` in `parsec` can parse an expression more conveniently, but above all, you need to know the basic of `parsec`.

Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off something that works on your examples. Try this:

```
evalExpr :: String -> Int
evalExpr xs = foldl f (0 +) xs 0

f :: (Int -> Int) -> Char -> (Int -> Int)
f v ch | ch == '+' = (v 0 +)
       | ch == '-' = (v 0 -)
       | ch == ' ' = v
       | otherwise = (v (read [ch] :: Int) +)
```

So the main difference to yours is that the accumulator in the fold is a function that takes in one Int and produces one Int, instead of just being an Int.